# Whitney sum via Gysin

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

Let $E_1\to E\to E_2$ be a short exact sequence of vector bundles. The Whitney sum formula says that $e(E)=e(E_1)e(E_2)$, i.e. that the Euler class is multiplicative.

Is there a proof of this fact based on the definition of the Euler class via the Gysin sequence
$$\cdots\ \longrightarrow \ H^{*-2\text{rk}E}(X)\ \stackrel{e(E)}{\longrightarrow}\ H^*(X)\ \longrightarrow\ H^*(SE)\ \longrightarrow\ \cdots\;\;?$$
I know the proof of Whitney sum by the splitting principle, but don't know any proof more directly in terms of the above definition which does not go via the splitting principle.

Comment: Are you specifically interested in a proof that does not use a splitting of the short exact sequence of vector bundles?

Comment: @TomGoodwillie Yes, I'd say that's an accurate interpretation of the question. I'm secretly interested in whether you can prove the Whitney sum formula working as much as possible just with formal properties of the category of sheaves on a space (the six functors, the Gysin sheaf sequence,...), but I suspect that question boils down to the one I've written above.

Comment: How are you used to defining Euler class? You say you get it from the Gysin sequence? I suppose you get the Gysin sequence from the Thom isomorphism? My usual explanation for multiplicativity of Euler class is an (external) product formula for the Thom class. I would think about how to make sense of the latter when sequences don't always split.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie Do you have a reference to the usual explanation you mentioned? To answer your question, from the sheaf point of view, writing $i:X\to E$ for the zero section and $j$ for its complementary closed embedding, we have the distinguished triangle $i_!i^!k\to k\to j_*j^*k\to$ in $\text{Sh}(X)$, taking cohomology of which gives the Gysin sequence. In particular, taking cohomology of $i_!i^!k\to k$ is multiplication by the Euler class.